# Benefit of kernel module compiled inside kernel?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

What's the benefit of compiling kernel modules into the kernel (instead of as loadable modules)?

Comment: See also: [What is the benefit of compiling your own linux kernel?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/905/what-is-the-benefit-of-compiling-your-own-linux-kernel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends. If you have a small amount of memory, the use of modules may improve the resume as they are not reloaded every time (I found it significant on 2 GiB of RAM but not on 4 GiB on traditional harddrives). This is especially true when due to some bug in the battery module (regardless of being compiled-in or as module), it took very long to start (several minutes). Even without bug on gentoo I managed to shorten time (reported by `systemd-analysis`) from 33s to 18s just by changing from statically compiled kernel to modules - 'surprisingly' the start of kernel changed from 9s to 1.5s.

Also, when you don't know what hardware are you going to use, modules are clearly beneficial.

PS. You can compile even vital drivers as modules as long as you include them in initrd. For example, distros will include the filesystem of /, drivers of harddrive etc. in initrd on installation.

Comment: Do you mind reading this answer again, carefully. I would have, but I don't know what you meant to say in place, e.g. *...on traditional harddrives*.

Comment: I meant magnetic ones (I don't have any experience with SSD).

Comment: I've tried to make this more readable. Can you check if I didn't screw it up.

Comment: Thanks. I just finished the exam session so I hadn't had time to look on it.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no speed difference.

I think you will gain a few kB of kernel memory as the granularity of allocations is one page, so on typical architecture each module wastes an average of about 2kB (½ page) per would-be module. Even on embedded systems, that's hardly significant. You also gain a little disk space as the modules can be compressed in the same go as the kernel; that can be more relevant in embedded systems with little storage.

If you can dispense with modules altogether, you save a little kernel memory (no need for the module loader), disk space (no need for the module utilities), and system complexity (no need to include module loading as a feature in your distribution). These points are quite attractive in some embedded designs where the hardware is not extensible.

Comment: To access a symbol in a module is a tiny bit slower (an indirection is involved). But the added flexibility (can load/unload as required, don't have to build a hand-tailored kernel for the exact hardware in use, ...) is well worth it (unless you are building for a very constrained environment that doesn't ever change).

Answer (score 4):

A couple potential benefits. Performance is an arguable one. You'd avoid some runtime overhead associated with a dynamic loader, but I doubt that's a big deal unless you're depending on a real-time scheduler.

If you're taking advantage of large pages on your system, then perhaps creating a larger static kernel image means you make more efficient use of the page descriptor cache. Some systems will 'cage' the kernel so that it packs tightly into one memory locality, which can alleviate some amount of delay due to minor, and possibly major, page faults.

It might suit you, architecturally, to deliver One Big Image, arguing that fewer independent modules is easier to maintain and the loss of flexibility is not important. A lot of this kind of reasoning ventures into matters of style and practice.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's necessary. If you compile some **vital** driver (e.g. SCSI driver) as a module your system won't boot.

Another great candidate for *not* compiling as a module is the filesystem type of the root partition. If the kernel doesn't understand `ext3` to read `/lib/modules/` how will it load modules from it ?

Think about it this way: to use modules the kernel needs to know enough about your system to to read and load kernel modules. Use that and trial and error :-)

Comment: I'm thinking about _some_ performance improve? Is there any at all?

Comment: In the past people have went to great lengths to produce the smallest possible kernel with only what is *required*. Today this has largely changed. In fact, whenever you first load a module you will suffer a small performance hit. That is not to say you should compile everything in the kernel :-) See this: http://www.articleinput.com/e/a/title/The-Linux-Kernel-module-code-and-and-kernel-boot-up-measurements/

Comment: for not-vital driver or functionality is there any benefit? for example if I just want to use terminal and bunch of network utility without other need or functionality. is there any benefit if I just compile all needed module and driver inside kernel without loadable module?

Comment: Bull. A system will boot fine with a SCSI driver as a module in an initrd. That's what they are for.

Comment: Yes... provided the module for that is in an initrd that the kernel can understand...

Answer (score 1):

I statically compile every driver for built-in hardware inside the kernel. Exception would be hardware which is not permanent (usb connected hardware, for example).

As my hardware configuration is not likely to change anytime soon, I don't bother with modules.